# LayerDrawable draws the drawables in same size?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Hi i am trying to draw two icons that are different sizes, one of the icons is just a background boarder type and the other icon is the symbol.

When i draw both, the symbol icon gets resized bigger to fit same size as the background icon.

Here is my code

```
  drawableSelectedIcons[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.background);

    drawableSelectedIcons[1] = r.getDrawable((R.drawable.symbol);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawableSelected = new LayerDrawable(drawableSelectedIcons);
```

Comment: Did you try to change your drawable scale value?

Comment: How do u do that programatically? the background image is something like 200x200 while the symbol image is only 120x120 so how come i have to scale/resize it manually?

Comment: You only have two layers?

Comment: Why don't you set the bigger image as background and the smaller image as src in an ImageView?

Comment: yes only two layers i have

Answer (score 4):

`R.drawable.symbol` is a Bitmap? Than it's loaded as BitmapDrawable. It has gravity. Depending on gravity bitmap is positioned inside drawable's bounds. Try to set gravity to Gravity.CENTER.

You can do it this way:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) r.getDrawable((R.drawable.symbol); // be careful with this cast
db.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)

drawableSelectedIcons[1] = bd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you just have that Image in your layout, this should be enough for what you want:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/symbol" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: For adding it dinamically to your layout, use:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.symbol);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    addContentView(imageView, params);
```

Comment: Needs to be rendered dynamically